# merge in oracle missing keyword using

Tags: oracle, h2

I have used merge in H2 in memory db, it works fine for me.
merge into

```
quickbooks_companies(COMPANY_NAME,ACCESS_TOKEN,ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,DATE_TOKEN_RETRIEVED)
key (COMPANY_NAME)
values('${companyName}',#[message.payload.accessToken],#[message.payload.accessTokenSecret], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

When I try to run same in Oracle db it gives missing keyword USING.

I tried this way, but did not work:

```
merge into quickbooks_companies('COMPANY_NAME','ACCESS_TOKEN','ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET') USING key (COMPANY_NAME) values('My Company','11223344','99887766');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your intention is to do an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE` depending on whether a row exists with the specified `company_name`, the Oracle syntax would be something like

```
MERGE INTO quickbooks_companies dest
  USING( SELECT 'My Company' company_name,
                '11223344' access_token,
                '99887766' access_token_secret
           FROM dual ) src
     ON( dest.company_name = src.company_name )
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
     SET dest.access_token = src.access_token,
         desc.access_token_secret = src.access_token_secret
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT( company_name, access_token, access_token_secret )
     VALUES( src.company_name, src.access_token, src.access_token_secret )
```